# Se muestra basura al imprimir dato en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa en lenguaje C, practicando con un enunciado de un parcial que tuve de estructuras anidadas con vectores. Tengo un problema para realizar el 1er enunciado y no sé por qué me muestra basura al imprimir el primer dato.

El 1er enunciado es

> El campo ultimos_pedidos almacena la fecha en las que el cliente realizó los últimos pedidos.
> En el caso de que el cliente aun no haya hecho 5 pedidos, las fechas "vacias"
> serán struct fecha con todos sus campos en 0.
> Si el cliente hubiera hecho más de 5 pedidos, en este vector siempre tendremos los 5 últimos.

Debajo les dejo mi código:

```
/*El campo ultimos_pedidos almacena la fecha en las que el cliente realizó los
últimos pedidos.
En el caso de que el cliente aun no haya hecho 5 pedidos, las fechas "vacias"
serán struct fecha con todos sus campos en 0.
Si el cliente hubiera hecho más de 5 pedidos, en este vector siempre tendremos
los 5 últimos.

2) Realice otra función llamada clientes_ordenados2 con este prototipo:
void clientes_ordenados2(struct cliente[], int n);
Debe mostrar en pantalla los nombres y teléfonos de los clientes ordenados
alfabéticamente. Para cada cliente informar además cuántos pedidos realizó (es
un número <= 5).
3) Si aun tiene tiempo, construya el main para probar estas funciones. Puede
utilizar ingresos por teclado o bien datos fijos con resultados conocidos.*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define CANTIDAD 2
#define PEDIDOS 10


struct fecha {
     int dia; 
     int mes;
     int anio;
};
struct cliente {
    char nombre[30];
    int telefono;
    struct fecha ultimos_pedidos[5];
};
void INICIALIZAR(struct cliente cli_ord[], int, int);
void CLIENTES_ORDENADOS(struct cliente cli_ord[], int);
void MOSTRAR_ORDEN(struct cliente cli_ord[], int n);
void CLIENTES_ORDENADOS2(struct cliente cli_ord[], int);
int main(){
    
    struct cliente datos[CANTIDAD]; 
    INICIALIZAR(datos, CANTIDAD,PEDIDOS);
    CLIENTES_ORDENADOS(datos, CANTIDAD);
    MOSTRAR_ORDEN(datos, CANTIDAD);
    CLIENTES_ORDENADOS2(datos, CANTIDAD);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void INICIALIZAR(struct cliente cli_ord[], int n, int x){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<x;j++)
        cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].dia=0;
        cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].mes=0;
        cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].anio=0;
}
        

//1) Realice una función que recibe un vector de clientes y su largo
/*Debe mostrar en pantalla el teléfono y nombre de todos los clientes, ordenados
según la cantidad de pedidos que han hecho, de manera decreciente.*/
void CLIENTES_ORDENADOS(struct cliente cli_ord[], int n){
    int i,j,k;
    
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\nNombre: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(cli_ord[i].nombre);
        
        
        printf("\nTelefono: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&cli_ord[i].telefono);
        
        
        printf("\nCANTIDAD MAXIMA DE PEDIDOS REALIZADOS [HASTA %d]: ", PEDIDOS);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &k);
        
        
        for(j=1;j<=k;j++){
            printf("\nFecha de pedido xx/xx/xxxx: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d/%d/%d", &cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].dia,&cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].mes,&cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].anio);
            
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        system("cls");
                
    }
}

void MOSTRAR_ORDEN(struct cliente cli_ord[], int n){
    int i,j,k;  
        
    for(i=n;i>0;i--){
        
        printf("\tCLIENTE %d______\n\n",i);
        printf("\tNOMBRE:%s",cli_ord[i].nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        
        printf("\tTELEFONO:%d\n",cli_ord[i].telefono);
        fflush(stdin);
    
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\tFECHA DE PEDIDOS\n\n");
        for(j=k;j>0;j--){
            printf("\t%d.%d/%d/%d\n\n", j,cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].dia,cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].mes,cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].anio);
        }
    }
}
void CLIENTES_ORDENADOS2(struct cliente cli_ord[], int n){
    int i,j,k;
    struct cliente aux[n];
        
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
            if(strcmp(cli_ord[j].nombre,cli_ord[j+1].nombre)>0){
            
            strcpy(aux,cli_ord[j].nombre);
            strcpy(cli_ord[j].nombre,cli_ord[j+1].nombre);
            strcpy(cli_ord[j+1].nombre,aux);    
            }
            
        printf("\n\tCLIENTES ORDENADOS ALFABETICAMENTE\n");
         for( i=0; i<n ; i++){
            
            printf("\nNOMBRE: %s", cli_ord[i].nombre);
        
            printf("\nTELEFONO:%d\n",cli_ord[i].telefono);
            fflush(stdin);              
    
            for(j=0;j<k;j++){
            printf("CANTIDAD DE PEDIDOS %d",j);
            fflush(stdin);  
                }
        
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: en inicializar, porque si la cantidad de fechas son 5, vas hasta 10?

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como estoy entendiendo tu código, la función `INICIALIZAR` pone todos los datos de todas las estructuras a cero. Lo haces con la siguiente llamada:

```
INICIALIZAR(datos, CANTIDAD,PEDIDOS); // CANTIDAD = 2, PEDIDOS = 10
```

La función entonces recorre los **dos primeros** elementos de `datos` y les asigna valores cero:

```
void INICIALIZAR(struct cliente cli_ord[], int n, int x){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<x;j++)
        cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].dia=0;
        cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].mes=0;
        cli_ord[i].ultimos_pedidos[j].anio=0;
}
```

Dado que `n` tiene valor dos (`2`), el bucle `for` externo recorrerá **sólo** los dos primeros elementos de `cli_ord`, el elemento en el índice cero y el elemento en el índice uno. Por otro lado, el bucle interno iterará desde el índice cero al índice nueve teniendo `ultimos_pedidos` disponibles sólo los índices del cero al cuatro; así que ejecutar ese código puede dar lugar a un fallo en tiempo de ejecución.

Sabiendo que los elementos en los índices cero y uno están inicializados a cero, veamos que pasa cuando se muestra haciendo la siguiente llamada:

```
MOSTRAR_ORDEN(datos, CANTIDAD); // CANTIDAD = 2
```

La función recorre los elementos en orden inverso **empezando por el índice dos**:

```
void MOSTRAR_ORDEN(struct cliente cli_ord[], int n){
//                                               ^ <--- 'n' vale '2'.
    int i,j,k;  
        
    for(i=n;i>0;i--){
//      ^ <--- 'i' empieza en '2'
        printf("\tCLIENTE %d______\n\n",i);
```

Dado que sólo los dos primeros elementos (índices cero y uno) se han inicializado a cero, el elemento en el índice dos (en la tercera posición) no ha tenido ninguna inicialización y ni siquiera existe (la formación<sup>1</sup> sólo tiene dos elementos) por tanto muestra "*basura*".

#### Propuesta.

La función `INICIALIZAR` es un sobresfuerzo innecesario, para poner todos los datos a cero se puede aprovechar el hecho de que toda la información está en memoria anexa y hacer un `memset`:

```
int main(){
    
    struct cliente datos[CANTIDAD]; 
    memset(datos, 0, sizeof(datos));
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. La [netiqueta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netiqueta) básica nos dice que escribir en mayúsculas equivale a gritar mientras que en el contexto de C los identificadores en mayúsculas se suelen usar para constantes; ninguna de tus funciones es una constante por lo tanto: usa minúsculas o [CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) o [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).
2. No es necesario pre-declara las variables de indexado de bucle antes de usarlas, puedes declararlas dentro del bucle.
3. Reordenar una formación<sup>1</sup> moviendo sus elementos es tremendamente ineficiente, más aún si los elementos tienen gran tamaño o son complejos o contienen datos que no pueden ser movidos. Mejor reordena usando índices.
4. Usa nombres auto-explicativos, `CLIENTES_ORDENADOS` y `CLIENTES_ORDENADOS2` nos da pocas pistas de qué hace cada función, sugiero los nombres `orden_alfabetico` y `orden_pedidos`.

Siguiendo esas recomendaciones tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define CANTIDAD 2
#define PEDIDOS 10

struct fecha {
    int dia; 
    int mes;
    int anio;
};

struct cliente {
    char nombre[30];
    int telefono;
    struct fecha ultimos_pedidos[PEDIDOS]; // Usa las constantes que declaras
};

void muestra_cliente(struct cliente c)
{
    int pedidos = 0;
    for (int indice = 0; indice != PEDIDOS; ++indice, ++pedidos)
        if (c.ultimos_pedidos[indice].dia == 0)
            break;

    printf
    (
        "Nombre: %s\n"
        "Telefono: %d\n"
        "Pedidos: %d\n",
        c.nombre, c.telefono, pedidos
    );
}

void orden_alfabetico(struct cliente cli[CANTIDAD])
{
    int indices[CANTIDAD] = { 0, 1 };

    for (int a = 0; a != CANTIDAD - 1; ++a)
    {
        for (int b = a + 1; b != CANTIDAD; ++b)
        {
            if (strcmp(cli[indices[a]].nombre, cli[indices[b]].nombre) > 0)
            {
                int aux = indices[a];
                indices[a] = indices[b];
                indices[b] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int indice = 0; indice != CANTIDAD; ++indice)
        muestra_cliente(cli[indices[indice]]);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct cliente datos[CANTIDAD];
    memset(datos, 0, sizeof(datos));

    strcpy(datos[0].nombre, "Wenceslao");
    datos[0].telefono = 123456;
    datos[0].ultimos_pedidos[0].dia = 1;
    datos[0].ultimos_pedidos[1].dia = 2;
    datos[0].ultimos_pedidos[2].dia = 3;
    datos[0].ultimos_pedidos[3].dia = 4;

    strcpy(datos[1].nombre, "Ambrosio");
    datos[1].telefono = 654321;
    datos[1].ultimos_pedidos[0].dia = 1;
    datos[1].ultimos_pedidos[1].dia = 2;

    orden_alfabetico(datos);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRRb9owEH6Of8WNalIQlBJo@7CMSWjsoS9dpXXaA4uQYzuttcRmcTJ1q/jt7Bw7kKYS20MU89135/u@u8DOHxjb78@kYnnNxXtTcaknjx9IBymleuhBPJephcgZF5lUAj4ub@9vVssVzA7Q3afVzerzF4imhGCRmlWQCfZI4ZkEUlXAJY3BHQthYneiSuqY7OJDCsulUJWwSZhbgtJFWor1fJr4jErkItMKs4IXt9R5JQttNlvBJddm7dtJYri4gK@GQk4NMK1MRbG@gZ@1AC5YTktqmgZ@acmhqAVWpRvfRtjrig2JV@OvgQVMsZNMlxBaWCoumWjQ9vxm0VoTw2jkwDGefIUhCQKZQcgmfQWOmkzQOFhgRcsM0Az6A7sNtjimKiNBiOjgtnHpHbw139XAAvfeJYS4h@5cWY@MEWIT5@4Y2KS1ddwqI8EQB@Nt0SUXakPzjKaikky/8iWX63YlkoNHToA5RtCXZ5iOIQJr@NE16gyj1qvDZp1DZA2jKBvrHckpkimMbDTtJlhyaj2y7MZSbJIV29A217ZCk@QouoOnB3zY2NzUcBtaP@GFx/zYR9rfnWDaC6Y2iPkNuiPNsyP/3JauIIfalvqb2e3eb0riJtZ8YVSq0I6uGUZvWpxWujMVbK8QhRFV2ATGdkJG/hE6c8BwaIdlzdz@dsh6enRx8E0o7CGneoC84BBvFwrVRbP55dV1N9hf9anfchzqCVbUsmanWLOWNT/Fmresy1fioo64Jb61kV1t0Qtt11eX81nUDf6Htui0NhK8@t7cIGyoFFVdKvuvs9vv/wI)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.